# How to migrate from Hits to Topdocs in Lucene c#

Tags: c#, lucene

I have a program made with lucene 2.9 and I am trying to migrate it to lucene 3.0, I have the next code:

```
    public IEnumerable<SampleDataFileRow> Search(string searchTerm)
    {
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(luceneIndexDirectory);
        QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("LineText", analyzer);

        Query query = parser.Parse(searchTerm);
        Hits hitsFound = searcher.Search(query);
        List<SampleDataFileRow> results = new List<SampleDataFileRow>();
        SampleDataFileRow sampleDataFileRow = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < hitsFound.Length(); i++)
        {
            sampleDataFileRow = new SampleDataFileRow();
            Document doc = hitsFound.Doc(i);
            sampleDataFileRow.LineNumber = int.Parse(doc.Get("LineNumber"));
            sampleDataFileRow.LineText = doc.Get("LineText");
            float score = hitsFound.Score(i);
            sampleDataFileRow.Score = score;

            results.Add(sampleDataFileRow);
        }

        return results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).ToList();
    }
```

I already have this:

```
    public IEnumerable<SampleDataFileRow> Search(string searchTerm)
    {
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(luceneIndexDirectory);
        QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, 
                                                "LineText", analyzer);
        Query query = parser.Parse(searchTerm);
        TopDocs topdocs = searcher.Search(query, 1000);
        List<SampleDataFileRow> results = new List<SampleDataFileRow>();
        SampleDataFileRow sampleDataFileRow = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < topdocs.ScoreDocs.Length; i++)
        {
            sampleDataFileRow = new SampleDataFileRow();
            Document doc = searcher.Doc(i);
            sampleDataFileRow.LineNumber = int.Parse(doc.Get("LineNumber"));
            sampleDataFileRow.LineText = doc.Get("LineText");
            float score = topdocs.ScoreDocs(i);
            sampleDataFileRow.Score = score;

            results.Add(sampleDataFileRow);
        }

        return results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).ToList();

    }
```

But I have problems with this part:

```
   float score = topdocs.ScoreDocs(i);
```

How I would get the score of the hits found? Many thanks in Advance!

Comment: Have you done any googling?  Even VS's intelisense says what to do. `topdocs.ScoreDocs[i].Score`

Comment: That worked! thanks, sorry, I am new with Lucene, and I really don't know where to start looking, also, if you could help me with another thing, int the for, I put (int i = 0; i < topdocs.ScoreDocs.Length; i++) Is that right? or it would be (int i = 0; i < topdocs.TotalHits; i++) ? Many thanks in advance!